# What is the background music when Danzo run away from Sasuke with one hand?

Tags: naruto, music

What is the the background music in Naruto: Shippuden season 10 episodes 210 "The Forbidden Visual Jutsu".

When Danzo run away from Sasuke with only one hand and Sasuke follow him?

Music start([9:46 in this Youtube video](https://youtu.be/XNBnCjtG-bY?t=585)), End([11:32 in this Youtube video](https://youtu.be/XNBnCjtG-bY?t=692)).

Answer (score 1):

This is that slow, gloomy-sounding theme with the guitar intro that often plays in scenes with Sasuke in it.

I believe this theme is an unreleased soundtrack. The song doesn't show up in Naruto Shippuden OST I, II, or III, in any case.

I searched "naruto shippuden sasuke theme unreleased" on YouTube and [this unofficial version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uhe70uLY9T0) popped up.